# XSLT condition to happen only once in foreach

Tags: xslt

```
        Source Xml : 
    <Lot>
            <LotDetails>
                <GCode>Ship</GCode>
                <ProductQuantity>2</ProductQuantity>
            </LotDetails
            <LotDetails>
                <GCode>Reject</GCode>
                <ProductQuantity>4</ProductQuantity>
            </LotDetails>
            <LotDetails>
                <GCode>Gross</GCode>
                <ProductQuantity>3</ProductQuantity>
            </LotDetails>
            <LotDetails>
                <GCode>Acceptable</GCode>
                <ProductQuantity>5</ProductQuantity>
            </LotDetails>
       </Lot> 
       <Lot>

         <LotDetails>
                <GCode>Ship</GCode>
                <ProductQuantity>2</ProductQuantity>
            </LotDetails
            <LotDetails>
                <GCode>Reject</GCode>
                <ProductQuantity>4</ProductQuantity>
            </LotDetails>
            <LotDetails>
                <GCode>Gross</GCode>
                <ProductQuantity>3</ProductQuantity>
            </LotDetails>
            <LotDetails>
                <GCode>Acceptable1</GCode>
                <ProductQuantity>5</ProductQuantity>
            </LotDetails>
       </Lot> 

      <LotDetails>
                <GCode>Ship1</GCode>
                <ProductQuantity>2</ProductQuantity>
            </LotDetails
            <LotDetails>
                <GCode>Reject</GCode>
                <ProductQuantity>4</ProductQuantity>
            </LotDetails>
            <LotDetails>
                <GCode>Gross</GCode>
                <ProductQuantity>3</ProductQuantity>
            </LotDetails>
            <LotDetails>
                <GCode>Acceptable1</GCode>
                <ProductQuantity>5</ProductQuantity>
            </LotDetails>
       </Lot> 
        TargetXml Field :

    <Lot><LotQty>5</LotQty></Lot>
   <Lot> <LotQty>2</LotQty></Lot>
    <Lot><LotQty>3</LotQty> </Lot> 

        Here the condition to check to map the target field is :

            If LotDetails/GCode = "Acceptable" and the corresponding ProductQuantity  not (null and zero)

            <LotQty> --> 5 [taken from the corresponding ProductQuantity ]

            else if LotDetails/GCode = "Ship" and the corresponding ProductQuantity not (null and zero)

            <LotQty> --> 2

            else if LotDetails/GCode = "Gross" and the corresponding ProductQuantity not (null and zero)

            <LotQty> --> 3

            else 

            <LotQty> --> 0

        Here the LotQty should happen only once for a particular iteration of <Lot> based on any of the conditions 
        if any first condition is satisfied then   the map  LotQTY from the corresponding ProductQuantity ?
When we use for each LotDetails- we get the qty correctly but it produces multiple results for LotQTY  inside each loop as below 
 <Lot>
        <LotQty>5</LotQty>
        <LotQty>2</LotQty>
        <LotQty>3</LotQty> 
 </Lot>

   <Lot>     
        <LotQty>2</LotQty>
        <LotQty>3</LotQty> 
 </Lot>
  <Lot>   
        <LotQty>3</LotQty> 
 </Lot> 

When i only use IF conditions with out for each  the qty is always selected from the first matched condition 
<Lot><LotQty>5</LotQty></Lot>
 <Lot> <LotQty>5</LotQty></Lot>
  <Lot><LotQty>5</LotQty> </Lot


What i need is as below  is only one lotQty for each lot based on first satisfied condition with the corresponding qty 


  <Lot><LotQty>5</LotQty></Lot>
   <Lot><LotQty>2</LotQty></Lot>
    <Lot><LotQty>3</LotQty></Lot>

Not sure on the template mach usage a being a beginner on xslt usage
```

How to get the correct LotDetails/ProductQuantity based on the the corresponding  LotDetails/GCode with out using a for each ?
Any ways to dynamically pass the satisfied condition from the if and choose the correct ProductQuantity with that LotDetails or choose the ProductQuantity from the current node ?

```
  Please let know xslt experts on the best way to do this ?
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please show the expected result in the given example and add more examples, if necessary. -- FYI, `xsl:for-each` is not a loop and cannot be exited or continued. If you want a single result, do not use `xsl:for-each`.

Comment: @Dev, try putting the whole condition into an if tag or the match condition of the template. Otherwise, if you need that for-each for some reason, create xsl variable and use it as a flag. Once you have displayed the value you want, set the variable as false for ignoring any other value.

Comment: thanks for you inputs - i changes to a single if with out for each conditions

Comment: <xsl:if test="(LotDetails/GCode = &quot;Acceptable&quot; and LotDetails/ProductQuantity != &quot;0&quot;) or (LotDetails/GCode = &quot;Ship&quot; and LotDetails/ProductQuantity != &quot;0&quot;) or (LotDetails/GCode = &quot;Gross&quot; and LotDetails/ProductQuantity != &quot;0&quot;)">
    <tns:LotQty xml:id="id_130">
         <xsl:value-of select="LotDetails/ProductQuantity" xml:id="id_131"/>
      </tns:LotQty>
  </xsl:if>

Comment: What i need is in my second iteration of parent xml with multple elements as below :<LotDetails>
    <GCode>Ship</GCode>
    <ProductQuantity>2</ProductQuantity>
</LotDetails
<LotDetails>
    <GCode>Reject</GCode>
    <ProductQuantity>4</ProductQuantity>
</LotDetails>
<LotDetails>
    <GCode>Gross</GCode>
    <ProductQuantity>3</ProductQuantity>
</LotDetails>
<LotDetails>
    <GCode>Acceptable1</GCode>
    <ProductQuantity>5</ProductQuantity>
</LotDetails>  The LotQTY should corresponds to Ship '2' - but here it always selects firs correct option for qty [5]

Comment: How to get the qty from the corresponding node with out using for each ?

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<Lots>
    <Lot>
        <LotDetails>
            <GCode>Ship</GCode>
            <ProductQuantity>2</ProductQuantity>
        </LotDetails>
        <LotDetails>
            <GCode>Reject</GCode>
            <ProductQuantity>4</ProductQuantity>
        </LotDetails>
        <LotDetails>
            <GCode>Gross</GCode>
            <ProductQuantity>3</ProductQuantity>
        </LotDetails>
        <LotDetails>
            <GCode>Acceptable</GCode>
            <ProductQuantity>5</ProductQuantity>
        </LotDetails>
    </Lot>
    <Lot>
        <LotDetails>
            <GCode>Ship</GCode>
            <ProductQuantity>2</ProductQuantity>
        </LotDetails>
        <LotDetails>
            <GCode>Reject</GCode>
            <ProductQuantity>4</ProductQuantity>
        </LotDetails>
        <LotDetails>
            <GCode>Gross</GCode>
            <ProductQuantity>3</ProductQuantity>
        </LotDetails>
        <LotDetails>
            <GCode>Acceptable</GCode>
        </LotDetails>
    </Lot>
    <Lot>
        <LotDetails>
            <GCode>Ship</GCode>
        </LotDetails>
        <LotDetails>
            <GCode>Reject</GCode>
            <ProductQuantity>4</ProductQuantity>
        </LotDetails>
        <LotDetails>
            <GCode>Gross</GCode>
            <ProductQuantity>3</ProductQuantity>
        </LotDetails>
        <LotDetails>
            <GCode>Acceptable</GCode>
            <ProductQuantity>0</ProductQuantity>
        </LotDetails>
    </Lot>
</Lots>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Lots">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Lot">
            <xsl:copy>
                <Quantity>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="LotDetails[GCode='Acceptable' and ProductQuantity > 0]">
                            <xsl:value-of select="LotDetails[GCode='Acceptable']/ProductQuantity"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="LotDetails[GCode='Ship' and ProductQuantity > 0]">
                            <xsl:value-of select="LotDetails[GCode='Ship']/ProductQuantity"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="LotDetails[GCode='Gross' and ProductQuantity  >0]">
                            <xsl:value-of select="LotDetails[GCode='Gross']/ProductQuantity"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </Quantity>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Lots>
  <Lot>
    <Quantity>5</Quantity>
  </Lot>
  <Lot>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
  </Lot>
  <Lot>
    <Quantity>3</Quantity>
  </Lot>
</Lots>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael  for  your quick apt response - but i have few more issues .Could please let know if the copy command as below corresponds to input and output element <xsl:template match="/Lots">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Lot">
            <xsl:copy>

Comment: `xsl:copy` performs a shallow copy of the current node - in my example, `Lots` and `Lot` are so copied.

Comment: Thanks Michael  for  your quick apt response - but i have few more issues .Could please let know if the copy command as below corresponds to input and output element .This is because as i use this sample for the actual code  where input and output have different tag names the copy creates an unwanted input element tag in the output .Please let know if this comment is not clear

Comment: The expected output Tag 
    <Lot><LotQty> and actual result <Lots><Lot> doesn;t match .Any Thoughts ?

Comment: I am afraid this is not a good place to conduct an XSLT tutorial. I have copied the root `Lots` element in order to produce a well-formed XML result. If you don't want it, then remove the first `xsl:copy` instruction. Similarly, you can replace `<Quantity>` with `<LotQty>` to get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks Micheal for the perfect solution !